# Do the converses of [weak law of large numbers / central limit theorem] hold?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $\; X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3,...\;$ be independent and identically distributed (real-valued) random variables.

1.
Suppose $\frac1n \cdot\sum\limits_{m=0}^n X_m$ converges in probability. Does it follow that $\operatorname{E}(X_0)$ exists?

2.
Suppose $\operatorname{E}(X_0) = 0$ and that $\frac1{\sqrt n} \cdot\sum\limits_{m=0}^n X_m$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable.
Does it follow that $\operatorname{E}((X_0)^2)$ is finite?

(I already found that the converse of the strong law of large numbers holds.)

Comment: a remark.  The weak law fails for the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: A remark: your question can be also rephrased in the following way. Let $\varphi$ be the characteristic fonction of $X_0$, and assume for simplicity that $X_0$ is symmetric. 1': If $\varphi(t) = 1+ o(t)$ as $t\to 0$, does it follow that $E(X_0)$ exists (and is zero)? 2' If $\varphi(t)=1- t^2/2 + o(t^2)$, does it follow that $E(X_0^2)$ exists (and is $1$)?  

Comment: A classical example for 1'. is a symmetric integer-valued X with P(X=n)=P(X=-n)=c/(n^2log(n)). Then phi is C^1 but X is not integrable. On the other hand, if phi is C^2 then X^2 is integrable.

Comment: Ricky, does the last line of your post mean that you have a proof of 1.?

Comment: Didier, this gives a counterexample to 1, right? I think the last line in the question means that if one replaces, in 1, convergence in probability by a.s. convergence, then the answer is yes (by say the converse to Borel-Cantelli).

Comment: Necessary and sufficient conditions (in terms close to those you want) for the WLLN and the CLT can be found, e.g., in "Foundations of modern probability" by Kallenberg (Theorems 4.16 and 4.17). 

Comment: @Mikael, I did not write *counterexample* because 1. asks a question. But you are right, the example I recalled proves that the answer to 1. is "no".

Comment: @Ricky: the characteristic function of a real random variable $X$ is $\phi(t)=E(e^{itX})$, and is defined for any real $t$.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I was confusing that with the moment-generating function.

Comment: @Yvan: Am I missing something, or do those not actually address either of my questions?

Comment: @Ricky in the 2nd Edition it's Theorems 5.16 and 5.17

Comment: @pgassiat: Yes, thank you. I hadn't realized that there was a newer edition ;) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(As suggested, I promote my comment to an answer, with pgassiat's complement.)

Necessary and sufficient conditions (in terms close to those you want) for the WLLN and the CLT can be found, e.g., in "Foundations of modern probability" by Kallenberg (Theorems 4.16 and 4.17 in the first edition, Theorems 5.16 and 5.17 in the second edition).