# Rate of convergence in the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, limit-theorems

I'm working on a problem where I need information on the size of $E_n=|S_n-n\mu|$, where $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ is a sum of i.i.d. random variables and $\mu=\mathbb EX_1$. For this to make sense, the $(X_i)$ have to be integrable. In that case, the weak law of large numbers says $E_n/n$ converges to 0 in probability, while the strong law says $E_n=o(n)$ almost surely.

If $X_1$ is square integrable, then we get the (stronger) result $E_n/(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ converges to 0 in probablility. What I am looking for is a result for the case $\mathbb E|X_1|^\alpha<\infty$ for some $1<\alpha<2$. Back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest a result of the form $E_n=O(n^{1/\alpha+\epsilon})$ holds. I suspect a relationship with $\alpha$-stable laws and have tracked down Gnedenko and Kolmogorov's book, but find (1) their notation is quite hard to read; (2) they seem to mainly care about something that's not so important for me; namely a result of the Central Limit Theorem type. They impose extra conditions under which suitably scaled and translated versions of $S_n$ converge to a non-trivial distribution. I don't want to assume anything beyond an $\alpha$th moment inequality, but am looking for a correspondingly weaker conclusion giving upper bounds on $E_n$.

> Can anyone point me to some results about deviation from the mean for sums of iid random variables with $\alpha$th moments ($1<\alpha<2$)?

> In a similar vein, what if the random variables fail to have an $\alpha$th moment for some $\alpha<1$. Here I'd expect to see some kind of result telling me that if $S_n/a_n$ converges in probability to a constant for some sequence $(a_n)$, then that constant must be 0.

**Edit:**
Let me give a precise Chebyshev-like statement I would really like to be true.

Let $(X_n)$ be iid; $\mathbb EX_1=0$ and $\mathbb E|X_1|^\alpha<\infty$ for some $1<\alpha<2$. 
Then $\mathbb P(|S_n|>t)<C_\alpha n\mathbb E|X_1|^\alpha/t^\alpha$, where $C_\alpha$ is a constant that only depends on $\alpha$ (I have guessed the bound based on "symbol-bashing" with the $\alpha$-stable law and believe it's at least "dimensionally correct".)

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but doesn't  a CLT-type  result give you exactly what you want?  In the finite-variance case, the classical CLT says that $(S_n - \mu n)/n^{1/2}$ converges weakly, so as a result $E_n/n^{1/2 + \epsilon} \to 0$ weakly and hence in probability (standard result).  So a CLT-type result telling you that $(S_n - \mu n)/ n^{1/\alpha}$ converges in distribution would imply that $E_n / n^{1/\alpha + \epsilon} \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: @Nate: Don't you need a second moment condition to apply CLT?

Comment: Right.  In the infinite second moment case, by "CLT-type result" I'm talking about a Kolmogorov-Gnedenko style stable law limit theorem giving the weak convergence of $(S_n - \mu n)/n^{1/\alpha}$ (typically the weak limit is a stable law, not the normal distribution).

Comment: Sorry @NateEldredge for the misunderstanding. So yes. I hope that a K-G stable law limit theorem would do the trick. It's just that I did not find a reference for such a theorem that didn't have a bunch of extra conditions (about slowly varying densities etc). If you know where I can find a statement of the type you're mentioning, that will probably resolve (at least the first part of) my issue.

Comment: I don't know an exact reference either, but I suspect that with a little work you can show that a distribution satisfying $E|X|^\alpha < \infty$ will satisfy the K-G hypotheses.

Comment: Related to your other questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73647/do-the-converses-of-weak-law-of-large-numbers-central-limit-theorem-hold

Comment: So it doesn't seem likely that $\mathbb E|X|^\alpha<\infty$ will be sufficient for the averages to converge to the $\alpha$-stable law: after all if this condition holds, then so does $\mathbb E|X|^\beta<\infty$ for $\beta<\alpha$. As far as I could tell (without claiming to really understand it), it looked as though the things proved to be in the domain of attraction of the $\alpha$-stable law had infinite $\alpha$th moments (the $\alpha$-stable law certainly has this property).

Comment: You'll also need $\: |\mathbb{E}X_1\hspace{-0.02 in}| < \infty \:$ in order to reach the conclusions you claim from the laws of large numbers. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Perhaps you will be interested in Sanov's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanov%27s_theorem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An early occurence of such bounds is in the theorem of Theorem of vonBahr and Eseen

vonBahr, B., Esseen C.-G.: Inequalities for the rth absolute moment of a sum of random
variables, $1\leq r \leq 2$. Ann. Math. Statist. 36, No.1, 299-393 (1965).

Theorem: Let $X_i$ be independent (not necessarily i.i.d.) zero mean random variables. Then, for $\alpha\in [1,2]$,
$$E|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|^\alpha\leq C_\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^\alpha\,.$$
($C_\alpha$ is explicit)

Applying Markov's inequality in your setup gives
$$P(|S_n|>t)\leq C_\alpha n E|X_1|^\alpha t^{-\alpha} $$
as you wanted.

Note: the moment condition certainly does not imply convergence to $\alpha$-stable - one would need some regularly varying conditions on the tail for that.

Note2: A good summary (up to late 70s) of estimates of this kind (mostly from the Russian school) are in Nagaev's Annals of Probability paper (1979). Petrov's 1975 book is also a good resource - in particular the VonBahr-Essen bound is mentioned there (on page 60).

Comment: Improvements and generalizations of the von Bahr--Esseen bound were given recently in the paper at http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afa/1435763999 (also available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5350).

Answer (score 5):

If we assume that the $X_i$ are iid in $L^p$ for some $p\in ]1,2[$, then we have:

$$ a.e. \ \ {1 \over n} \sum_{k=0}^{n−1} X_k=E(X_0)+o(n^{1/p−1})$$

This follows from the Kolmogorov three series theorem. This is done in the book of Durrett, [probability, theory and examples](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf), theorem 2.5.8 (now theorem 2.5.12 with the 5th version of the book).

Note that if you are not interested by the exact exponent, then the standard quick
$L^2$ proof gives you such an estimate.

Comment: Thanks - but isn't Var$(Y_i)$ infinite?

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. I'll look in Durrett tomorrow.

Comment: @quas the book is on his webpage, I have provided a link. Define $Y_i = X_i {\bf 1}_{|X_i|\leq i^{1/p}} / i^{1/p}$, check that $\sum Var(Y_i)$ is finite, this gives a.e. convergence of $\sum Y_i$, then apply the Kronecker lemma and Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: So I did look at Durrett. I have a paper copy that does not seem to include Thm 2.5.8, but the online version is as you say; and also includes an answer to the other question I asked. Thanks again.

Comment: I realize this question is a number of years old, now, but do either of you know if it is possible to get a uniform constant for the little-o?

Comment: @pseudocydonia I don't know. The answer of Ofer Zeitouni contains an explicit bound that may be useful. The three series approach does not give much information. I have updated the link to Durrett's book.

Answer (score 4):

Your exact question seems to be answered by Lenny Baum and Melvin Katz:

- *Convergence rates in the law of large numbers*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **120** (1965), 108-123, https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1965-0198524-1

Comment: Thanks @Igor. This does seem very close to my question. I'll see if I can extract a Chebyshev-like result (which is what I really want) from this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is a concentration inequality for heavy-tail distributions.  How about this one:

Barthe, F., Cattiaux, P., & Roberto, C. (2005). [Concentration for independent random variables with heavy tails](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505492). *Applied Mathematics Research eXpress*, 2005(2), 39-60.

Also, please take a look at the [Bernstein inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)).

Comment: Thanks @Taha. So I think Bernstein inequalities are based on exponential moments (which diverge in my setting); I was unable to pick out useful results from the paper by the French authors either.

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure someone should have derived the concentration inequalities for heavy-tail distributions.  I tried to look at this: [Robust Estimation of High-Dimensional Mean Regression](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2150.pdf), but their lemmas require me to read the entire paper to understand. I'll look into the robust statistic literature to see what I can find.